# S=5eb7474c89555... in URL? What is it? How do I get rid of it?

Tags: url, navigation

I setup the links in my header navigation using `{path='site'}`, `{path='about'}`, etc. When I view the rendered pages, the links have an extra parameter S=.

Examples:

```
http://example.com/index.php/S=5eb7474c89555bd5d9e41ec21a99566906803a2d/
http://example.com/index.php/S=5eb7474c89555bd5d9e41ec21a99566906803a2d/site/about
```

What is the S parameter and how do I get rid of it?

I thought perhaps it was session variable or something, but I can't seem to find any information about it in the user docs.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi if you go to admin > security & privacy > security and session preferences. Then change the user session type to "cookies only" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set User Session Type to Cookies in Admin =>  Security & Privacy => Security and Sessions.